# I am running into Assertion error while running command `npm run group`

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-watch

Can someone help me with this ?
This is the error I get every time I run `npm run group`

> assert.js:374
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
>       at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
>       at Gulp.task (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
>       at Object. (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/gulpfile.js:361:6)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
>       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
>       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>       at execute (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^4.0.0/index.js:36:18)
>       at Liftoff.handleArguments (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/index.js:201:24)
>       at Liftoff.execute (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:201:12)
>       at module.exports (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/flagged-respawn/index.js:51:3)
>       at Liftoff. (/home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:191:5)
>       at /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:149:9
>       at /home/gaurav/Desktop/GSOC/CarbonFootprint/node_modules/v8flags/index.js:138:14 {
>     generatedMessage: false,
>     code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
>     actual: false,
>     expected: true,
>     operator: '=='
>   }
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! carbon-footprint@6.0.2 group: `gulp group`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the carbon-footprint@6.0.2 group script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /home/gaurav/.npm/_logs/2020-01-15T19_29_53_228Z-debug.log

And this is the **gulpfile.js**.I understand that the error is at line 368(as far as I can understand)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Server = require('karma').Server;
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
var argv = require('yargs').argv; 
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
var deleteLines = require('gulp-delete-lines');
var stripDebug = require('gulp-strip-debug');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');
var del = require('delete-empty');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var cheerio = require('gulp-cheerio');
var jeditor = require('gulp-json-editor');
var variables = require('./buildVariables.json');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var merged = require('merge-stream');
var lintFiles = [
  'Source/**/*.js',
  '!Source/**/*.min.js',
  '!Source/Chrome/background/google-maps-api.js'
];
var gulpSequence = require('gulp-sequence');

var validatorFilter = gulpFilter('**/validatorServer.js', { restore: true });
var doMinify = argv.debugApp === undefined ? true : false;
var transpiledFiles = gulp
  .src('Source/Core/**/*.js')
  .pipe(babel())
  .pipe(validatorFilter)
  .pipe(
    gulpif(
      !doMinify,
      deleteLines({
        filters: [/Raven(.|\s)+?;/g]
      })
    )
  )
  .pipe(validatorFilter.restore);
var chromeBuildpath = 'Build/Chrome/';
var safariBuildpath = 'Build/Safari/CarbonFootprint.safariextension/';
var webExtensionBuildpath = 'Build/WebExtension-Firefox/';
process.env.mode = argv.debugApp === undefined ? 'production' : 'development';

gulp.task('prepareTest', function() {
  var es6files = [
    'Source/Core/core/storageManager.js',
    'Source/Core/core/CarbonFootprintCommon.js',
    'Source/Core/core/TrainsCarbonFootprintCore.js',
    'Source/Core/core/helpers/flightDataHelper.js',
    'Source/Core/core/FlightsFootprintCommon.js',
    'Source/Core/core/FlightsCarbonFootprintCore.js',
    'Source/Core/core/MapsCarbonFootprintCore.js',
    'Source/Core/core/validator/basicValidator.js',
    'Source/Core/core/validator/flightsValidator.js',
    'Source/Core/core/validator/mapsValidator.js',
    'Source/Core/core/validator/trainsValidator.js',
    'Source/Core/core/inform.js',
    'Spec/Mocks/SentryServerMock.js',
    'Spec/Mocks/MockHelper.js',
    'Spec/**/*Spec.js'
  ];
  var jsonFiles = 'Source/Core/**/*.json';
  return merged(
    gulp
      .src(es6files)
      .pipe(babel())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('Build/test')),
    gulp.src(jsonFiles).pipe(gulp.dest('Build/test'))
  );
});
gulp.task('karma', function(done) {
  new Server(
    {
      configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
      singleRun: true
    },
    done
  ).start();
});

gulp.task('eslint', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(lintFiles)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});


gulp.task('localesChrome', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Locales/**/*.json')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(chromeBuildpath + '_locales'));
});

gulp.task('coreChrome', function() {
  var linkFilter = gulpFilter('**/knowMore.html', { restore: true });
  var validatorFilter = gulpFilter('**/validatorServer.js', { restore: true });
  return merged(
    transpiledFiles
      .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(chromeBuildpath)),
    gulp
      .src(['!Source/Core/**/*.js', 'Source/Core/**'])
      .pipe(validatorFilter)
      .pipe(
        gulpif(
          !doMinify,
          deleteLines({
            filters: [/Raven(.|\s)+?;/g]
          })
        )
      )
      .pipe(validatorFilter.restore)
      .pipe(linkFilter)
      .pipe(
        cheerio(function($, file) {
          $('#rating-link')
            .attr('href', variables['chrome']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> ${variables[
                'chrome'
              ]['storeName']}`
            );
          $('#store-link-1')
            .attr('href', variables['firefox']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<img src="${variables['firefox'][
                'badge'
              ]}" class="img-responsive" />`
            );
          $('#store-link-2')
            .attr('href', variables['safari']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<img src="${variables['safari'][
                'badge'
              ]}" class="img-responsive" />`
            );
        })
      )
      .pipe(linkFilter.restore)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(chromeBuildpath))
  );
});

gulp.task('specificChrome', function() {
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var validatorFilter = gulpFilter('**/validatorServer.js', { restore: true });
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Chrome/**')
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, stripDebug()))
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(validatorFilter)
    .pipe(
      gulpif(
        !doMinify,
        deleteLines({
          filters: [/Raven(.|\s)+;/g]
        })
      )
    )
    .pipe(validatorFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(chromeBuildpath));
});

gulp.task('coreSafari', function() {
  var linkFilter = gulpFilter('**/knowMore.html', { restore: true });
  return merged(
    transpiledFiles
      .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(safariBuildpath)),
    gulp
      .src(['!Source/Core/**/*.js', 'Source/Core/**'])
      .pipe(linkFilter)
      .pipe(
        cheerio(function($, file) {
          /*
        * TODO Safari is currently linked to https://safari-extensions.apple.com.
        * Update variables.json with appropriate link once app is published
        */
          $('#rating-link')
            .attr('href', variables['safari']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> ${variables[
                'safari'
              ]['storeName']}`
            );
          $('#store-link-1')
            .attr('href', variables['chrome']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<img src="${variables['chrome'][
                'badge'
              ]}" class="img-responsive" />`
            );
          $('#store-link-2')
            .attr('href', variables['firefox']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<img src="${variables['firefox'][
                'badge'
              ]}" class="img-responsive" />`
            );
        })
      )
      .pipe(linkFilter.restore)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(safariBuildpath))
  );
});

gulp.task('chromeShared', function() {
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var validatorFilter = gulpFilter('**/validatorServer.js', { restore: true });
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Chrome/background/**')
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, stripDebug()))
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(validatorFilter)
    .pipe(
      gulpif(
        !doMinify,
        deleteLines({
          filters: [/Raven(.|\s)+?;/g]
        })
      )
    )
    .pipe(validatorFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(safariBuildpath + 'background/'));
});

gulp.task('specificSafari', function() {
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var validatorFilter = gulpFilter('**/validatorServer.js', { restore: true });
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Safari/**')
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, stripDebug()))
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(validatorFilter)
    .pipe(
      gulpif(
        !doMinify,
        deleteLines({
          filters: [/Raven(.|\s)+?;/g]
        })
      )
    )
    .pipe(validatorFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(safariBuildpath));
});

gulp.task('localesSafari', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Locales/**/*.json')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(safariBuildpath + '_locales'));
});

// WebExtension Building
gulp.task('localesWebext', function() {
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Locales/**/*.json')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(webExtensionBuildpath + '_locales'));
});

gulp.task('coreWebExt', function() {
  var linkFilter = gulpFilter('**/knowMore.html', { restore: true });
  return merged(
    transpiledFiles
      .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(webExtensionBuildpath)),
    gulp
      .src(['!Source/Core/**/*.js', 'Source/Core/**'])
      .pipe(linkFilter)
      .pipe(
        cheerio(function($, file) {
          $('#rating-link')
            .attr('href', variables['firefox']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<i class="fas fa-external-link-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> ${variables[
                'firefox'
              ]['storeName']}`
            );
          $('#store-link-1')
            .attr('href', variables['safari']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<img src="${variables['safari'][
                'badge'
              ]}" class="img-responsive" />`
            );
          $('#store-link-2')
            .attr('href', variables['chrome']['storeLink'])
            .html(
              `<img src="${variables['chrome'][
                'badge'
              ]}" class="img-responsive" />`
            );
        })
      )
      .pipe(linkFilter.restore)
      .pipe(gulp.dest(webExtensionBuildpath))
  );
});

gulp.task('specificWebExt', function() {
  var jsFilter = gulpFilter('**/*.js', { restore: true });
  var manifestFilter = gulpFilter('**/manifest.json', { restore: true });
  var validatorFilter = gulpFilter('**/validatorServer.js', { restore: true });
  return gulp
    .src('Source/Chrome/**')
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, stripDebug()))
    .pipe(gulpif(doMinify, uglify()))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(validatorFilter)
    .pipe(
      gulpif(
        !doMinify,
        deleteLines({
          filters: [/Raven(.|\s)+?;/g]
        })
      )
    )
    .pipe(validatorFilter.restore)
    .pipe(manifestFilter)
    .pipe(
      jeditor({
        applications: {
          gecko: {
            id: 'carbon-footprint@aossie.org',
            strict_min_version: '53.0'
          }
        }
      })
    )
    .pipe(manifestFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(webExtensionBuildpath));
});

gulp.task('clearXAttr', shell.task(['xattr -rc ' + safariBuildpath]));

gulp.task('cleanChrome', function() {
  return del.sync(chromeBuildpath);
});

gulp.task('cleanSafari', function() {
  return del.sync(safariBuildpath);
});



gulp.task('cleanWebExt', function() {
  return del.sync(webExtensionBuildpath);
});


gulp.task('groupChrome', [
  'cleanChrome',
  'localesChrome',
  'coreChrome',
  'specificChrome'
]);
gulp.task('copySafariFiles', [
  'localesSafari',
  'coreSafari',
  'chromeShared',
  'specificSafari'
]);
gulp.task('groupWebext', [
  'cleanWebExt',
  'localesWebext',
  'coreWebExt',
  'specificWebExt'
]);

gulp.task('groupSafari', function(done) {
  runSequence('cleanSafari', 'copySafariFiles', 'clearXAttr', function() {
    done();
  });
});

gulp.task('group', [
  'groupChrome',
  'groupSafari',
  'groupWebext'
]);


gulp.task('test', gulpSequence('prepareTest', 'eslint', 'karma'));
```

I am a beginner in Npm and Javscript world, so please if you could explain all the error and reasons behind it, that would help me a lot.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `run-sequence` first of all.

Change this:

```
gulp.task('group', [   // this is gulp3 syntax, you are using gulp4 presumably
  'groupChrome',
  'groupSafari',
  'groupWebext'
]);


gulp.task('test', gulpSequence('prepareTest', 'eslint', 'karma'));
```

to

```
gulp.task('group', gulp.series(   // here was your main problem
  'groupChrome',
  'groupSafari',
  'groupWebext'
));


gulp.task('test', gulp.series('prepareTest', 'eslint', 'karma'));
```

So gulp v3 uses `gulp.task('someTaskName', ['taskA', 'taskB', etc.])`

gulp v4 uses `gulp.task('someTaskName', gulp.series('taskA', 'taskB', etc.))`

Search for gulp migration guide from v3 to v4 for more info.